# Decrypt on open, encrypt on save with Sublime

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I'm writing a simple plugin that:

- decrypts every file with a `.crypt` extension on load, prompting for a password
- encrypts them on save (not reasking for the password if already asked during load ; only asking for a password if it's a *new file* that will be saved)

In the code below, the encryption method is trivial: the `password` is an integer, and encrypting shifts every char of `+password`; decrypting shifts every char of `-password` (i.e. subtracts `password` to the value of every char). This is not a real encryption nor a safe method ; of course I'll replace this with AES encryption or similar later, but this example, this is enough to showcase the problem I have in this question.

```
import sublime_plugin, sublime

password = None

class PromptCryptCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        panel = self.window.show_input_panel("Enter password", "2", self.on_done, None, None)

    def on_done(self, pwd):
        global password
        password = int(pwd)
        self.window.run_command(action)

class EncryptCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        region = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        plaintext = self.view.substr(region)
        ciphertext = ''.join([chr(ord(c)+password) for c in plaintext])
        self.view.replace(edit, region, ciphertext)

class DecryptCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        region = sublime.Region(0, self.view.size())
        ciphertext = self.view.substr(region)
        plaintext = ''.join([chr(ord(c)-password) for c in ciphertext])
        self.view.replace(edit, region, plaintext)

class LoadSaveListener(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_load(self, view):
        global action
        if view.file_name().endswith(".crypt"):
            action = 'decrypt'
            view.window().run_command('prompt_crypt')

    def on_pre_save(self, view):
        global action
        if view.file_name().endswith(".crypt"):
            if password == None:  # password not entered yet, let's prompt for it
                action = 'encrypt'
                view.window().run_command('prompt_crypt')
            else:  # password already asked when file was loaded, 
                view.window().run_command('encrypt')
```

I'm having these problems that I don't know how to solve:

- I we re-save multiple times with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, the file is re-saved, i.e. re-encrypted. Example:

  ```
  plaintext = 'abc'
  password = 2
  after one CTRL+S, content = 'cde'
  after one more CTRS+S, content = 'efg'
  after one more CTRS+S, content = 'ghi' etc.
  ```

  I tried to solve this with `def on_post_save(view):` and **restore** the unencrypted plaintext after a save operation. It kind of works, but then, even if the file is saved and no change has been done, then Sublime *thinks the file is modified*! (because unencrypted plaintext has replaced the saved encrypted version of the file).
- When a `.crypt` file is loaded, the ciphertext is displayed in the editor window, how to hide this until the password is entered in the prompt?

Comment: Featured in super great live stream video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ih1BBGwayLc :) Thanks @OdatNurd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the whole something like this is not as clean and seamless as we might like it to be; the underlying system assumes that a `view` is associated with a file on disk and that any modifications should be tracked directly. So trying to represent the content of a `view` that is associated with a file using content that doesn't appear in that file is problematic.

Although it's not as seamless, something like having a command do it's own encrypted save in the background (which would leave two files present) and capturing the content of a view, closing it and recreating the original file from it fit more in line with how Sublime expects things to work.

> I tried to solve this with `def on_post_save(view):` and restore the unencrypted plaintext after a save operation. It kind of works, but then, even if the file is saved and no change has been done, then Sublime thinks the file is modified! (because unencrypted plaintext has replaced the saved encrypted version of the file).

Doing any sort of modification to the buffer marks it as being `dirty`, which is why this is happening. There is only two things that can remove this status from the file.

The more obvious of these is the `save` command; once Sublime persists the data to the disk it removes the `dirty` flag from the file,

The other is to mark the `view` as a scratch view by using `view.set_scratch(True)`; views that are scratch views don't display any sort of modification status at all, so you can use this to temporarily turn off the marker that says that the file is modified.

An issue with this is that once the file is marked as being `scratch`, it will never show as modified at all, no matter how many changes you make. Additionally this only stops Sublime from rendering the status as dirty; once the scratch state is removed the dirty status will return (even though `view.is_dirty()` will return `False` while the view is in scratch mode).

You can get around this to some extent by setting the view as `scratch` and then applying a view setting to it, and having an `on_modified` event listener that only triggers when that view setting is enabled and removes the `scratch` state (and the setting) so that the buffer appears to be unmodified until you make a modification.

This is not without its problems; for example you can undo back through the operation that replaced the encrypted version of the file with the plain text one, which may or may not be desirable.

An alternative here is to do the file encryption saves yourself by writing files to disk manually instead of letting Sublime do it for you; in that case you're in full control and don't require the content of the buffer to change, so it will only be dirty when it's supposed to be dirty. The down side is that this would leave an unencrypted version of the file laying around (though you could delete it `on_close` if desired).

> When a .crypt file is loaded, the ciphertext is displayed in the editor window, how to hide this until the password is entered in the prompt?

One way to do this would be to prepare a color scheme that has an identical foreground and background character and override the `color_scheme` setting in the `view` until after the password is entered, at which point you could remove it. That would hide the data from view.

An alternative is to capture the data from the file and then use `view.close()` to close the tab (you may also need to capture other information like the file name, for example). You would then be able to create a new empty view and populate it with the decrypted data (though you still need to do the same tricks as above so that it doesn't appear dirty.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in short, having a good and seamless UI/UX for that is not easy...  *An alternative here is to do the file encryption saves yourself by writing files to disk [...] The down side is that this would leave an unencrypted version of the file laying around*: Yes this is a big problem ; even if I `os.remove(...)` the unencrypted file, then anyone could "undelete" it. In short, I wanted the unencrypted data to be *never* written on disk storage, for security reasons. (unencrypted: only in RAM). Any idea about how to solve these problems?

Comment: The main issues are that only the `save` command can open a file chooser dialog and you can't mark buffers clean. So all roads to having a filename for your command go between having to use `on_pre_save` or somehow get the filename a different way and never use the `save` command at all, which is problematic. Apart from that, once your `view` has an assigned file name you can easily override the save key binding to run a different command so that you're in charge of the save, but that leaves you with having to juggle the dirty state of the file as noted above.

Comment: Thanks @OdatNurd. Is there a way to "decouple" the bytes saved on disk (i.e. the file `test.crypt` on disk) and the content of the editor "view"? i.e. the view *always* stays unencrypted without having to use a trick like `self.view.replace(edit, region, ciphertext)`, but during the save operation, the buffer to be saved to disk is modified, and the view is unchanged. It would be only the "serialization to disk" which would be modified, but never the view. Is this possible with Sublime?

Comment: There's no way that I know of to break the association between the `view` and it's backing file, so you would have to instead make sure that there's no connection at all (by using your own custom `save` command) so that the `view` is never associated with a file.

Comment: Oh good idea @OdatNurd: is there a way to override the original `save` / prevent Sublime itself to save the file to disk? i.e. ask Sublime to *not* write anything on disk when saving? Then I would implement myself the actuel write-to-disk IO operation during `on_pre_save` or  `on_post_save`. This solution would allow me to avoid the hack `self.view.replace(edit, region, ciphertext)` which created other problems (such as "dirty" , etc.).

Comment: You can use a command in place of `save` to do that, but then the save events won't trigger because you're not using the `save` command. The save command is also what prompts for a filename, which is problematic. I worked on this in my last live stream and the code that I came up with is in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/OdatNurd/b678313ee1cb719de1969f49a15b53dc) (though it doesn't fit your use case exactly because the unencrypted data is also saved)

Comment: Wonderful @OdatNurd, I'll read this during this week-end! Being curious, where do you do live coding stream? I'm interested to watch it :)

Comment: There's a link in the gist to the stream; generally Tuesdays are the days for streams, but that's changing for the month of December.

Comment: Great live stream @OdatNurd! I added a few comments in the gist.